# Particles falling through plane with collider

Tags: particles

I have particles coming out of an extruded half circle on top of a plane but they keep falling through even though I have a collider on in the plane. How do I fix this?
[image: picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is that you need to make sure that the emitter and the collision object need to share the same layer for them to affect each other in physics simulations. From your screenshot it looks like you are using at least two layers, so maybe that's it?